# Execute two First() in the same commit

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two queries with `First()`, and EF always executes against the database the query when detecting methods like `First`, `ToList`, etc.

My commit consists of the check if a new exists, and then check if the user has voted it.

```
int theId = 33;

// Check if the new exists
var theNew =
    await this.context
        .News
        .FirstAsync(x => x.Id == theId);

// The new doesn't exist
if (theNew == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}

// Check if the user has voted the new
var voted =
    await this.context
        .UserVoteNews
        .FirstAsync(x => x.UserId == this.UserId && x.NewId == theId);

if (voted == null)
{
    return BadRequest(@"User didn't vote");
}
else
{
    return Ok("User voted");
}
```

I've tried with

```
using (var dbContextTransaction = this.context.Database.BeginTransaction())
```

But the server executes the queries with FirstAsync before that

```
await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
dbContextTransaction.Commit();
```

Comment: You are trying to do a transactional _read_? If so, why? Your two queries do not change anything, so saving changes is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think you misunderstand what transactions are for. Transaction are (mostly) for *modifying* the database. If all you want to do is read, then there is usually no need to worry about commits and whatnot.

Second, there is no need for you to use transactions *at all* when working with EF, except in very specific use cases. You can simply do this:

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
    // Stuff
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I can see from your example that you have `this.context` which you presumably use throughout your class. The recommended approach is to not have a single context, but create a new one when it is needed like in the example I just showed. This allows you to effectively use EF's entity tracking, which removes the need for you to use transactions.

Within the `using` block, you can perform whatever (valid) operations you want involving the context, reads and writes. Any and all *changes* are tracked by EF and commited when you call `SaveChanges`. Read queries aren't performed when you call `SaveChanges`, but instead are sent to the provider as soon as they are converted.

Here is a revised version of your code:

```
using (var context = new Context()) // Create a new context for this
{
    int theId = 33;
    var theNew = await context.News.FirstAsync(x => x.Id == theId);

    if (theNew != null)
    {
        var voted = await context.UserVoteNews.FirstAsync(x => x.UserId == this.UserId && x.NewId == theId);

        // Returns are mutually exclusive so clean up by removing else clauses
        if (voted != null)
        {
            return Ok("User voted");
        }

        return BadRequest(@"User didn't vote");
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```

Note that I never call `SaveChanges` or `SaveChangesAsync`, because we haven't modified anything.

Comment: There are transactions that read, write and commit, transactions are not the misplaced concept here. However, there are no transactions with read part in EF because of the need to materialize values in order to map changes.

Comment: With this approach, the server execute FirstAsync() before the other queries.

Comment: @JohnDoe That will always be the case, since they are completely different queries. There is no way to execute them "together". You can move things around and have them be executed in sequence with nothing else in between, however that offers no real benefit.

Answer (score 1):

This can of behavior is impossible using only Entity Framework.

However, some third party library allows to do it.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

This library allows you to `Defer` query that are `Immediate` such `First` method.

The library allows you also to batch multiple queries via the `Future` features. So all pending query is executed in the same `commit` or database round-trip.

```
var theNewDeferred = context.News.DeferredFirst(x => x.Id == theId).FutureValue();
var votedDeferred = context.UserVoteNews.DeferredFirst(x => x.UserId == this.UserId && x.NewId == theId).FutureValue();

// Both FutureValue will be executed in the same database round-trip
var theNew = await theNewDeferred.ValueAsync();

if(theNew != null)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either I do not understand you or you do not understand the EF. A **read** operation will be send to the database as soon as the query is materialized, for example by calling `FirstAsync`. You seem to think the read query will be executed whenever you call `SaveChangesAsync` or `Commit` which is not the case. `SaveChangesAsync` will initiate **write** operations on the db. Like INSERTs, DELETEs and UPDATEs.